# I want to compute a variable in SPSS with "if"

Tags: spss, calculated-columns

[image]

I would like to create the last column.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
/*************************************/.
DATA LIST FREE /v1 v2 v3 v4 v5.
BEGIN DATA
1 2 99 4 5
99 2 3 99 5
1 99 3 4 5
1 2 99 99 5
1 99 99 99 5
99 2 99 99 99
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS1.
/*************************************/.
/* Solution1: Assumes v1 to v5 can hold any value from 1 to 5 */.
recode v1 to v5 (99,sysmis=sysmis) (else=copy).
do repeat v=v1 to v5.
if (any(v,1,4,5)) Target1=1.
if (any(v,2,3)) Target2=2.
end repeat.
compute TargetA=sum(Target1,Target2).

/* Solution2: Alternative solution which assumes v1 holds values 1 only v2 values 2 only ect... */. 
recode v1 to v5 (99,sysmis=sysmis) (else=1).
compute TargetB=sum(any(1,v1,v4,v5)*1, any(1,v2,v3)*2).
exe.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

- Your input file contains 5 columns, 1 per channel
- Each channel-specific column is filled with channel-specific identifier (1-5)
- When the column is empty, that channel is not used / not relevant for that observation
- You want to summarize the mix of channels used in new field (NewVar)
  You want to use the IF statement in the SPSS syntax

The answer above by JigneshSutar does not seem to do this. Also, you do not need the do-repeat-loops but can do this in 3 lines (+EXECUTE.) of syntax (using the data generator in the answer by JigneshSutar):

```
IF (V1 = 1 & V4 = 4 & V5 = 5)  NewVar = 1.
IF (V2 = 2 & V3 = 3)  NewVar = 2.
IF (V1 = 1 & V2 = 2 & V3 = 3 & V4 = 4 & V5 = 5)  NewVar = 3.
EXECUTE.
```

This syntax can easily be adjusted when the channel columns are filled with other values than the channel identifiers [1-5], for instance by using the missing function:

```
IF (MISSING(V1)=0 & MISSING(V4)=0 & MISSING(V5)=0)  NewVar = 1.
IF (MISSING(V2)=0 & MISSING(V3)=0)  NewVar = 2.
IF (MISSING(V1)=0 & MISSING(V2)=0 & MISSING(V3)=0& MISSING(V4)=0 & MISSING(V5)=0)  NewVar = 3.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: The first/initial solution I posted makes the assumption Var1 to Var5 can hold **any** values between 1-5, though the example data given perhaps suggests otherwise. The solution otherwise would be straight forward usage of IF logic. If the data is stored as you assume then this is very bad presentation of data and ought to be recoded and I update my post to propose a solution for this.